# Azure Functions input binding with version 4.x

Tags: azure-functions

When updating `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB` from Version `3.0.10` to `4.2.0` my input binding stops working and I could not find any explanation (after hours of searching and trying to narrow down the issue further).
This is the code running in 3.0.10:

```cs
[FunctionName("GetById")]
public static Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "GetById/{id}")] HttpRequest req,
    string id,
    ILogger log,
    [CosmosDB(databaseName: MagicValues.CosmosDbName,
        collectionName: MagicValues.CosmosContainerName,
        ConnectionStringSetting = MagicValues.CosmosDbConnectionName,
        SqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM c where c.id = {id}",
        PartitionKey = "partitionKey")] IEnumerable<dynamic> myEnum)
{
    log.LogInformation($"id={id}");
    return Task.FromResult<IActionResult>(new OkObjectResult(myEnum.First())); //contains a valid value for V3 but not in V4. the soluton must make use of SqlQueryAttribute
}
```

when I update to Nuget package the only change in the code is that `ConnectionStringSetting` is now callled `Connection`. Apart from that the code compiles and runs. but now the enumerable is always null.

The problem only occurs if I try using input bindings. If I make explicit use of the CosmosDbClient it works in both 3.x and 4.x.

This is my .csproj-File:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos" Version="3.32.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Azure.Core">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Users\ftkjs\.AzureToolsForIntelliJ\AzureFunctionsCoreTools\v4\4.30.0\Azure.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you switched the Azure Function runtime as well? What are the versions of .NET and Functions runtime?

Comment: Do you have isolated-runtime function app?

Comment: Hi Vlad, thanks for your help. it should be inprocess. I added the content of my csproj to the question.

Comment: Could you provide full code snippet related to the section `//myEnum contains values`

Comment: Updated the sample code a bit, @HariKrishna